# How to quickly search for today's date in a file?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, search, command-line-window

##### Question

How does one effectively find today's date in a file?
The format of the date is given by GNU's `date(1)`'s command as:

```bash
$ date '+%a %d-%m-%Y'
Mon 16-08-2021
```

##### What I already tried

This is how I got this to work right now.

**Step 1.** I have defined a vimscript `:Date` command to output the wanted format:

```
function Date()
   read !date '+\%a \%d-\%m-\%Y'
   -1
   join
endfunction
command Date :call Date()
```

**Step 2** I open up the `command-line-window` in search mode with `q/`.
**Step 3** I run `:Date` to output today's date in the `command-line-window`.
**Step 4** I press `<Enter>` to find the date.

Steps 2, 3, and 4 have to be repeated every time to find today's date.
So, oftentimes, I just search for the date manually (e.g. `/Mon 16-08-2021`).
How can I make this process more efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will search for today's date:

```
/<C-R>=strftime('%a %d-%m-%Y')<CR><CR>
```

You can define a mapping to create a shortcut, for example, to search with `<Ctrl>G` in normal mode you can use:

```
nnoremap <C-G> /<C-R>=strftime('%a %d-%m-%Y')<CR><CR>
```